# How to I determine the maximum number of iterations in K-means clustering?

Tags: r, k-means

[In the documentation of kmeans](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html), the default value of iter.max is 10:

kmeans(data, modes, iter.max = 10, weighted = FALSE, fast = TRUE)

I don't understand why. And I also wonder how to determine the value of inter.max

Comment: kmeans does not require in general a large number of iterations. I agree with @MrFlick that this question is more suitable for Cross Validated. If your model converges you don't need other iterations.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the default should be to iterate to convergence.

1. K-means converges hard. There is a finite number of possible assignments, so unlike many other iterative optimization algorithms, you don't spend time at fine-tuning weights. You stop when no points change to another cluster.
2. *Good* k-means algorithms (*not* the stupid textbook algorithm) have cheap iterations. Often, all the remaining iterations take little time compared to the first one or two. So with a good algorithm it does not matter much whether max iterations is 10 or 1000.